# Does Google Cloud Compute Engine allows Ubuntu image?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Cloud Compute Engine, and am reading the section of Custom Image of their developer documentation, and then found that they allow custom Debian and CentOS images. So I wonder if Ubuntu, which is also Debian based, is allowed or not. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it supports Ubuntu images, get the list with:

`$ gcloud compute images list
NAME                                 PROJECT          FAMILY
...
ubuntu-1204-precise-v20160801        ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1204-lts
ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20160627         ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1404-lts
ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20160721         ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1604-lts
...`

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to put the work in, you can [build an image from scratch](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) using any linux distribution you like.

Comment: Definitely I'll try as soon as I have time, and I will post result here no problem

Comment: Any progress? Or hopefully an official image.

Answer (score 0):

The current list of images available are:

```
projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140408                  
projects/debian-cloud/global/images/backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20140408 
projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20140408           
projects/rhel-cloud/global/images/rhel-6-v20140408                      
projects/suse-cloud/global/images/sles-11-sp3-v20140306
```

No Ubuntu specific image is available.

If you have [`gcutil`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/), you can see this list using the [`gcutil listimages`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/reference/image#listimages) command.

Comment: gcutil is deprecated